# How to get the total physical memory in Bash to assign it to a variable?

Tags: linux, bash

How can I get the total physical memory in bytes of my Linux PC?

I need to assign it to a bash script variable.

Comment: This question makes very little sense as-is. Please try to rewrite it to be more specific.

Comment: I've just rewritten it. For me it is very specific, I have to get the total physical memory (RAM) of my PC and assign it to a variable in my bash script.

Answer (score 79, accepted):

```
grep MemTotal /proc/meminfo | awk '{print $2}'
```

The returned number is in KB

Comment: it seems you have answered your own question. nevertheless, use one awk command to do the job. `awk '/MemTotal/{print $2}' /proc/meminfo`

Comment: To include conversion to a different base (e.g. GB) you can use `grep MemTotal /proc/meminfo | awk '{print $2}' | xargs -I {} echo "scale=4; {}/1024^2" | bc`

Comment: @turtlemonvh Or you ca do `awk '/MemFree/ { printf "%.3f \n", $2/1024/1024 }' /proc/meminfo`. Credit goes [here](awk '/MemFree/ { printf "%.3f \n", $2/1024/1024 }' /proc/meminfo).

Comment: Bytes: `awk '/MemFree/ { printf "%i\n", $2*1024 }' /proc/meminfo`

Comment: Note that this (and other similar answers using `/proc/meminfo`) are not including the Swap memory. There are also totals for swap in `/proc/meminfo` which you would have to add, if you want to include swap.

Answer (score 26):

```
phymem=$(awk -F":" '$1~/MemTotal/{print $2}' /proc/meminfo )
```

or using free

```
phymem=$(LANG=C free|awk '/^Mem:/{print $2}')
```

or using shell

```
#!/bin/bash

while IFS=":" read -r a b
do
  case "$a" in
   MemTotal*) phymem="$b"
  esac
done <"/proc/meminfo"
echo $phymem
```

Comment: I like this one because you can pass in `-m`, `-g`, etc., to `free` to get it in different units :)

Comment: Very good summary answer, thank you. Further more I'd change appropriate line to `while read -r a b c` to strip the units.

Answer (score 14):

I came up with this one under the assumption, that the physical memory will be the first number in free's output:

```
free -m | grep -oP '\d+' | head -n 1
```

This allows you to configure free to output the unit you want (-m, -g, ...) and it is independent of the system language (other answers depend on the "Mem:" string in free's output which may change based on the language).

Answer (score 9):

How about

```
var=$(free | awk '/^Mem:/{print $2}')
```

Comment: no spaces between "=" sign when assigning variable. use `$()` syntax wherever possible.

Answer (score 2):

> I'll try to make this answer self explanatory, just keep up with me.

To get the **description of memory**, you can use the `free` utility :

```
free -t
```

**Output** (in KB):

```
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:        8035900     3785568      324984      643936     3925348     3301908
Swap:       3906556      271872     3634684
Total:     11942456     4057440     3959668
```

To extract all of these **values** from this output in a single column :

```
free -t | grep -oP '\d+'
```

**Output** (in KB):

```
8035900
3866244
266928
650348
3902728
3214792
3906556
292608
3613948
11942456
4158852
3880876
```

> **Note** : Minute difference can be there in values, which doesn't matter most of the times.

If you just want to get the **`total` physical memory** (mem+swap), it is the 10th value in above output :

```
free -t | grep -oP '\d+' | sed '10!d'
```

**Output** *(on my PC)*:

```
11942456
```

> **Note**: All the above outputs are in `Kilo Bytes`. If you want in `Mega Bytes` or `Giga Bytes` just append `-m` or `-g` after `-t` in
>   above `free` commands respectively.
>
> *For Example :*
>
> ```
> free -t -g | grep -oP '\d+' | sed '10!d'
> ```
>
> **Output** *(in Giga Bytes on my PC)* :
>
> ```
> 11
> ```

Answer (score 1):

Silly inline python version, which looks overly complicated, but is actually kind of useful.

```
freemem=$(echo -e 'import re\nmatched=re.search(r"^MemTotal:\s+(\d+)",open("/proc/meminfo").read())\nprint(int(matched.groups()[0])/(1024.**2))' | python)
```

It returns the memory in GB.

Comment: I think you have a stray "r" in your 're.search(r"^MemTotal...")'

Comment: @kd88 I think it's ok. That's just the notation for a raw string in python. See the intro section of the regex docs for an explanation: https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html

Answer (score 1):

If someone need a human readable:

```
var=$(free -h | awk '/^Mem:/{print $2}')
```

result:

```
1.9G
```